# Bayesian factor BF10 and normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, multiple-comparisons

I´m trying to understand whether it is possible to use Bayesian Factors for contrasting data whose distribution is not normal.

Should I apply any correction, or BF10 does not care about the distribution of the data?

My data are reaction time (RT) data, collected by the same group in 4 different conditions. I want to check if comparing the 4 conditions (A vs B, B vs C, C vs D) H0 is more likely than H1, H1 being that the means are significantly different.

Comment: How do you normally calculate the Bayes Factor?

Comment: You can use the Bayes factor to test hypothesis whatever the distribution of your data, and whatever prior, but you still need to specify these.

Comment: I am using the pairwise_ttests function from pingouin [here](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.pairwise_ttests.html) in Python3.